# Multilevel Child grid in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on HTML5 and Javascript app, I am working on Multi Level Child Grids using kendo grid.

Example : Parent -> Child->grandchild.

Can this be achieved using kendo grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can simply define another detail init on the child grid like this

```
function detailInit(e) {
                    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                            },
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverSorting: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            pageSize: 10,
                            filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.EmployeeID }
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        detailInit: detailInitGrandChild,
                        dataBound: function() {
                            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                        },
                        columns: [
                            { field: "OrderID", width: "70px" },
                            { field: "ShipCountry", title:"Ship Country", width: "110px" },
                            { field: "ShipAddress", title:"Ship Address" },
                            { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: "300px" }
                        ]
                    });
                }
```

Check out this example http://dojo.telerik.com/uQEx

Comment: Hi cwishva Thank you :). I was looking for this one